# Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site.

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, licensing

My site is a developer site and I did enable the siteloading feature through the powershell script. But I still get this error whenever I try to deploy an app.

Is this because of the licensing? I am using SharePoint Online 2013.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site